# How to pass variables through three or more zsh programs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zsh

So I have several scripts that I've made to help myself, but apparently after moving to a different OS (from mint to ubuntu) and installing zsh they stopped working.
This is one of my cases called the 'cweb' script which was supposed to let me in a specific directory (through the terminal). But apperantly the $location is not being edited through the whole script therefore I don't move a directory, anyone have a clue?
I admit I've made several changes to the codes since then but yet they don't work as I expected them to.

If someone could take a look and help me here..

I open the terminal and I write 'cweb'

```
cweb
What would you like to run?
Press f to frontend, b to backend. [f/b]
f
Reading frontend directory ('frontend_dir') text file..
Work Directory Location Exported.

Moving onto the chosen directory..
There you go!
```

So in when I typed in the terminal vim ~/.zshrc
I wrote

```
SCRIPTS_DIR=/home/skillz/Desktop/Desktop_Items/Work/Scripts
export PATH="$PATH:$SCRIPTS_DIR"
export SCRIPTS_DIR=$SCRIPTS_DIR/Supporting_Scripts
```

Inside the scripts path I have the 'cweb' script which is

cweb:

```
#!/bin/zsh
$SCRIPTS_DIR/ask_server
echo "Moving onto the chosen directory.."
cd $location
echo "There you go!"
exec zsh
```

ask_server:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "What would you like to run?"
while true; do
  echo "Press f to frontend, b to backend. [f/b]"
  read -k 1 fb
  echo
  case $fb in
    [Ff]* ) zsh $SCRIPTS_DIR/read_frontend_dir && break;;
    [Bb]* ) zsh $SCRIPTS_DIR/read_backend_dir && break;;
    * ) echo "Unrecognized Option."
  esac
done
echo $location
```

read_frontend_dir:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "Reading frontend directory ('frontend_dir') text file.."
file=$SCRIPTS_DIR/Dirs/frontend_dir.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
  location="$line"
done <"$file"
echo "Work Directory Location Exported."
```

read_backend_dir:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "Reading backend directory ('backend_dir') text file.."
file=$SCRIPTS_DIR/Dirs/backend_dir.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
  location="$line"
done <"$file"
echo "Work Directory Location Exported."
```

frontend_dir.txt

```
/home/skillz/cweb-frontend/
```

backend_dir.txt

```
/home/skillz/skillz-coding-website/
```

TL;DR
I run a script called CWEB which prompts me with a question.
I can either type f or b, by my desicion it will read a different directory and pass me over to that directory.
The script is working fine and all, it gets all the correct scripts to run one by one. but eventually cd-ing to the returned location doesnt work.
I printed $location after receiving it and apperantly it is empty..
Any clue?

Anyone has an idea why it doesn't move me to the 'chosen directory'?
It does exist and `cd` there works fine.

Comment: Thanks ahead for time investors!

Comment: I am running everything on zsh but the title is #!/bin/bash

Comment: Thanks for fixing `$!/bin/*sh` (etc) to `#!/bin/*sh`. . Learn to use you debug/status messages to show you what values are now assigned to your variables, i.e. rather than just `echo "Work Directory Location Exported."`, do `echo "Work Directory Location=${location} Exported."` . Hm.. and below your write `The real problem is that it can't use the variable $location`. (Is this the real/main problem?) Too bad you have 100+ lines of text that people will have to decipher to understand your problem. ....

Comment: You should also learn how to debug your script using `set -x ; export PS4='$LINENO >';`. This will show you each line of code that is executed and will show the value of the variables being used. Some shells (not sure about zsh) scope variables inside of a while loop to just the sub-shell created by the while loop, and then the variable is empty outside of the while loop. That sounds like what is happening to you. I use `ksh93` all the time (still) and this is not a problem there, so I can't give you an exact idea how to solve that problem. ....

Comment: It gets asked here at least once a month, so search for `[bash] while loop variable empty` or similar phrases. Good luck.

Comment: I edited out the references to Bash as clearly all of your code is Zsh. Maybe your fundamental problem is not realizing that they are different.

Comment: Indeed there was a difference between bash and zsh, glad it is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly before calling any script I need to make it save all the variables in zsh, by typing `source` at the beginning of the code, all the enviroment will be kept between the scripts and it will come to live great again.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work because `read` is a Bash shell built-in. `zsh` has a `read` function also, but works kind of different.

From the Zsh documentation:

> -n
>   Together with -c, the number of the word the cursor is on is read. With -l, the index of the character the cursor is on is read. Note that the command name is word number 1, not word 0, and that when the cursor is at the end of the line, its character index is the length of the line plus one.

Example:

```
# Zsh:
% read -n 1 tmp
ls
% echo $tmp

% read tmp
ls
% echo $tmp
ls
% read -n 1 tmp
ls sl
% echo $tmp
sl
```

What you want is the '-k' option if you still want to migrate to Zsh:

> -k [ num ]
>   Read only one (or num) characters. All are assigned to the first name, without word splitting. This flag is ignored when -q is present. Input is read from the terminal unless one of -u or -p is present. This option may also be used within zle widgets.
>
> Note that despite the mnemonic ‘key’ this option does read full characters, which may consist of multiple bytes if the option MULTIBYTE is set.

[Bash read manual](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)
[Zsh read manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) (Scroll to read).

Comment: Assuming this is the solution, in my way it still let me read it correctly.

Comment: The real problem is that it can't use the variable $location

Comment: Are you sure that `$SCRIPTS_DIR/Dirs/frontend_dir.txt` exists and is a single line file? IF you have an additional, empty line at the end of that file `$location` will of course be empty since you overwrite the variable: `location=$line`. So if `wc -l $SCRIPTS_DIR/Dirs/frontend_dir.txt` results in two lines, you have found your bug.

Comment: source solved it, I printed $location at the end of the reading and it actually was successfull